# The 'entityType' parameter must be an instance of 'EntityType'

Tags: javascript, breeze, hottowel

I'm just starting out with BreezeJS and using the HotTowel template with Asp.Net Web Api and EF

I've got to the point of trying to retrieve a record using  manager.getEntityByKey, using the example at http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/querying-locally

To test I'm using the code:

```
 var key = new breeze.EntityKey("LibraryItemCategory", 1);
            var entity = manager.getEntityByKey(key);
```

But when the code is called I get the error 'The 'entityType' parameter  must be an instance of 'EntityType' ' for the first line of code.

At the point the code is called the manager has the "LibraryItemCategory" entities loaded, and I have used Visual Studio to confirm the entityType shortName is "LibraryItemCategory"

Can anyone suggest what is wrong in the code or how I can get past this?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `EntityKey` constructor's first parameter must be an instance of `EntityType`, not the name of the type. [See the API doc](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityKey.html#method_%3Cctor%3E%20EntityKey).

Therefore, you'd do something like this

```
var type = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("LibraryItemCategory");
var key = new breeze.EntityKey(type, 1);
var entity = manager.getEntityByKey(key);
```

A bit clunky.

You might wonder *Why doesn't `EntityKey` accept the name of the type and use that to find the `EntityType`?*

Well ... it can't ... because the `EntityKey` "class" has no way to discover your EntityTypes; all EntityType info is held in a `MetadataStore` ... of which there could be many.

We have to get the type from a `MetadataStore`; in this example we get it from the manager's `metadataStore`.

p.s.: you must have populated `manager.metadataStore` before calling this code, either implicitly as a side-effect of your first query or explicitly as [when you call `fetchMetadata`](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html#method_fetchMetadata).

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, I had forgotten to 'Prime' the app by calling Metadata from the server so Breeze didn't understand what the type was